# Meaning of "chair of the panel" - equal to "chair of Committee" or just "discussion moderator" in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning, translation

From a [news report](https://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/898003):

> "Antipsychotics do not treat schizophrenia's negative symptoms, such as impaired cognition, restriction of emotions, and lack of ambition, symptoms that prevent people with the disorder from leading productive lives," said Alan Breier, MD, Indiana University School of Medicine, Indianapolis. The findings were presented here at the American Society of Clinical Psychopharmacology (ASCP) 2018 annual meeting.
>
> [...]
>
> Steven Marder, MD, Semel Institute at the University of California, Los Angeles, who was **chair of the panel**, told Medscape Medical News that he used to be skeptical about the utility of herbals and nutraceuticals.

What is the meaning of **chair of the panel** here? Does **panel** represent the whole body of persons who met to discuss the role of nutraceuticals in schizophrenia, or was there some subset, come "committee" consisting of choice members of the overall discussion?

When I consult En->Ru dictionaries and look for "[panel chairman](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=panel%20chairman)" I get a Russian phrase that equals "Committee chairman" (председатель комитета), but I think that maybe in this case there is no committee, just a free-flowing discussion and one guy who serves as its moderator. I want to make sure in order to translate correctly.

Comment: It depends on what the panel is.

Comment: I can't read the full context without signing up for things I don't want, but the bottom line here is no dictionary definition of ***panel*** (or ***committee, working group, task force, commission, forum, group,*** etc.) can answer your question. Either the nature of the specific panel is explicitly defined within the text or it isn't. If not, it's a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to refer to the leader of a [panel discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panel_discussion) that took place at the conference that was mentioned earlier. This role is usually called the "moderator", but the panel can be likened to a committee and "chair" would be understood as a synonym.